# ImportError: No module named all (scapy module)

Tags: importerror, scapy

[image: Screenshot 1]

I don't know what's the matter.

please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? If you are using python3 did you install the correct version of scapy? `pip3 install scapy-python3`, on python2: `pip2 install scapy`. Using virtual environments both were able to `from scapy.all import *` (python2 required other packages such as pcapy and dnet)

Comment: I had the same problem when I named my virtualenv folder 'scapy' ;) Just change your name of folder/file :)